# bluetooth is not working after updation

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, bluetooth, pulseaudio, bluez

am using pi 4 8GB for last 6 months everything was going well. Last week i updated my OS(raspbian). After that bluetooth is not working properly. i can able to pair a device successfully, but am not able to select my bluetooth device as an audio output.when i do that its showing an error like

> Failed to connect to bluetooth device - Device not found by pulseaudio

am having an one more os which was not updated recently

Answer (score 2):

It is a known issue on the PI4. Take a look at the forum thread:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=311457#p1864038

Comment: Wow! What a clusterf**k.

Answer (score 1):

by executing this command

> sudo apt-get install pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
>
> dpkg -l pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth

issue has been solved